# Media of WhatsApp app disappeared

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gallery, media-files

yesterday I noticed that my all media from WhatsApp application were deleted or disappeared. While I check the usage of the application, I saw that user storage is still big enough to store media (about 20 GB).
The media not deleted only from the gallery. It is also disappear from the media section at the chat (every chat).
What could happen? And if anybody know how to fix it and restore it?

I am using Nokia 8.3 with Android 12 operating system.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you by any chance "clear data" of the WhatsApp app, or use storage cleaner apps to free up the storage?

Comment: Nope, there is still the data app storage like it's still there (on the settings I see the app data usage and it's up to 20-25 GB)